# Hosting a WCF service for iOS and Android application back-end

Tags: android, .net, ios, wcf, hosting

I would like to create a WCF service for my server-side for multiple platforms (iOS and Android) to operate against (mainly sending data like text and images). I have a couple questions:

- Will WCF Soap or MVC3 WCF be suitable to accomplish this? I believe it should as I'm basically just posting data.
- Can WCF keep the data secure while being transfered?
- What type of hosting account would I need? I currently have a hostgator account for a personal site but I'm guessing I may need a "VPS" or virtual hosting account that gives me full control of IIS to point to the WCF endpoints? I'm quite unclear on this last item.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried doing any basic research like googling for "ios wcf",  "android wcf" or "hostgator wcf"? Because in doing so I have turned up lots of links that answer your questions.

Comment: Hi Peter, I don't see a specific answer for the last bullet and what I would appreciate is some knowledge from someone who has done something similar before. I am certain at this point I can send JSON data to a WCF service but am not sure if a basic windows web hosting account is the correct option for setting up my WCF back-end. I imagine it would have an IP though, so I guess it would work. Just wanted to ask if anyone had done similar with success.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is your friend here.

In service web.config, key points are:

```
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

And

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

In your .svc file use:

```
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
```

Lastly, in the service code I recommend http://json.codeplex.com/ over MS's built in JSON serializers.